# How to dissociate mutability from lifetime in Rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, mutability

I want to have two types (in my question-fitted examples I will mark them as `IdHandler` counting IDs, and `IdUser` using the IDs), where the dependent one of them should not outlive (hence, lifetimes) the dependency, and that's the only requirement. Figured the quickest solution would be using `PhantomData<&'...>`:

```rust
struct IdHandler {
    id_counter: u64,
}

struct IdUser<'a> {
    _a: PhantomData<&'a IdHandler>,
    id: u64,
}
```

Then, using a mutable reference with a specified lifetime, I made a function in `impl IdHandler` to create the users:

```rust
fn new_id_user<'a>(self: &'a mut IdHandler) -> IdUser<'a> {
    let res = IdUser {
        _a: PhantomData,
        id: self.id_counter,
    };

    self.id_counter += 1;

    res
}
```

Now, I will make a function that takes in a mutable reference and tries to make a pair of `IdUser`s:

```rust
fn f<'a>(id_handler: &'a mut IdHandler) -> (IdUser<'a>, IdUser<'a>) {
    let a1 = id_handler.new_id_user();
    let a2 = id_handler.new_id_user();
    (a1, a2)
}
```

And here's an example of how those types and functions may be used:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut id_handler = IdHandler { id_counter: 0u64 };

    let (a1, a2) = f(&mut id_handler);

    assert_eq!(a1.id, 0u64);
    assert_eq!(a2.id, 1u64);
    assert_eq!(id_handler.id_counter, 2u64);

    id_handler.stop(); // fn stop(self) {}
    // Ideally here 'a is dead,
    // so you can't perform operations on IdUser<'a>

    // assert_eq!(a2.id, 1u64);
}
```

Given the fact that `new_id_user(...)` only uses the mutability for a moment, and then hopefully "releases" it back (as it is not used any longer than the function call - I do not know the exact rule Rust uses, but it works without `_a`/`'a` or when `fn f(...) -> ()`), I'd expect `f(...)` to work just fine. However, the compiler has greeted me with following:

```rust
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*id_handler` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\main.rs:29:14
   |
27 | fn f<'a>(id_handler: &'a mut IdHandler) -> (IdUser<'a>, IdUser<'a>) {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
28 |     let a1 = id_handler.new_id_user();
   |              ------------------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
29 |     let a2 = id_handler.new_id_user();
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
30 |     (a1, a2)
   |     -------- returning this value requires that `*id_handler` is borrowed for `'a`
```

Does anyone know whether there is a solution that I'm missing, or am I doomed to allow `IdUser`s to outlive the `IdHandler`?

Comment: See [this link](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#9-downgrading-mut-refs-to-shared-refs-is-safe) on why the compiler is treating the return as a mutable borrow. I'm still not convinced the compiler shouldn't accept the code, but it currently doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot. Preserving a value with a lifetime will prevent the mutating the value from which it was derived even if you don't actually keep a reference to it. A common workaround if you want to ensure the lifetimes are bound while still being able to mutate is to use [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/interior-mutability.html) (via `Cell`, `RefCell`, `Mutex`, etc).

Here's a working example using [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html):

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::cell::Cell;

struct IdHandler {
    id_counter: Cell<u64>,
}

impl IdHandler {
    fn new_id_user<'a>(self: &'a IdHandler) -> IdUser<'a> {
        let res = IdUser {
            _a: PhantomData,
            id: self.id_counter.get(),
        };
    
        self.id_counter.set(self.id_counter.get() + 1);
    
        res
    }
}

struct IdUser<'a> {
    _a: PhantomData<&'a IdHandler>,
    id: u64,
}

fn f<'a>(id_handler: &'a IdHandler) -> (IdUser<'a>, IdUser<'a>) {
    let a1 = id_handler.new_id_user();
    let a2 = id_handler.new_id_user();
    (a1, a2)
}

fn main() {
    let mut id_handler = IdHandler { id_counter: Cell::new(0u64) };

    let (a1, a2) = f(&mut id_handler);

    assert_eq!(a1.id, 0u64);
    assert_eq!(a2.id, 1u64);
}
```

Comment: Using `Cell` or `RefCell` moves the checks to the runtime, similar to how missing an `'a` would (I would need to ensure `id`s would be valid during runtime), but less bad since the users of this (example) API would not see it. All in all, thank you very much, `Mutex` (would be `RefCell` if not `Sync`) has done it for my non-example use-case.

Comment: @KirillSemyonkin `Cell` or atomics don't have any checks at runtime. If you only have phantom (and not real) lifetime relationship with `PhantomData`, you can not use `new_id_user()` (and instead embed its code) or (last resort) use unsafe code.